# "and has as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals to “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.”"

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases, direct-objects, infinitive-constructions

I would like to ask you about the bold-faced part in the following sentence:

> (1) The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention defines social determinants of health as “conditions in the places where people live, learn, work, and play” that affect their health outcomes and **has as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals to “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.”**

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/medical-students-must-learn-how-social-factors-affect-health/

I think the subject of the sentence is "The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention," so the sentence will be like:

(2) The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention has as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals to “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.”

I would like to make sure that my understanding about (2) is correct.

(a) The object of the verb is "to “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all”."

(b) The prepositional phrase "as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals" is not the object of the verb but an adverbial phrase that is usually placed after the object.

(c) Then, the sentence could be paraphrased to:

The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention has to “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all” as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals.

(d) Given (c), is it okay if the object of the verb "has" is a to-infinitive? Is it okay even if double quotation marks are removed:

The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention has to create social and physical environments that promote good health for all as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals.

(e) Does the object have to be, for example, a gerund:

The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention has creating social and physical environments that promote good health for all as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals.

I would very much appreciate your comments!

Comment: The original sentence seems off, and I'd edit to bring the 'to' into the quote: Has, as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals,**"to** create ... environments."

Comment: This is bureaucratize written for bureaucrats—a good example of this sort of language.  It actually has very little content.

Comment: Your parse is not right. It is this:  The CDC **defines X** and has **as one of one its Healthy People Policy Y** [etc.] To have as one of its policies is standard English. [Your last sentence is not accurate, either]. Sorry. :)

Comment: I suggest that might be better served somewhere like SE English Language Learners, or Writing… As it stands, the exposition is worse than the main Question title, but so what? Almost irrelevantly, the particular combination of quotation marks is so highly unusual, it would  normally be inadmissible.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not clear as it stands mainly because the subject (the CDC) is subject of two verbs that go in two semantically incongruent directions.

1> The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention **defines** social determinants of health as “conditions in the places where people live, learn, work, and play” that affect their health outcomes and **has** as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals to “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.”

Strike "and" and stick an **it** or "The CDC" in there, and you're golden:

<strike>and</strike> **The CDC has** as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals ...

The contrast is between "social determinants" and "all". "Social determinants" disadvantage certain groups, which is an obstacle to egalitarian health outcomes.

With regard to your paraphrase. The paraphrase with **... has to** "create... " is incorrect, or at least ambiguous. The original is not expressing an obligation placed upon the CDC ("it **has to** do X", i.e. it must do X). The passage is quoting from another text. One of the quoted phrases is being folded into a sentence. Syntactically, **to** belongs with the plain infinitive **create**, not with **has*; the text from which the quote was lifted did not have **to**, apparently. It might have been clearer if the author had written:

> ... has as one of its goals "[to] create ..."

placing a word necessary for the syntax in brackets if it does not appear in the original quoted text.

The locution is *to have [something] as a goal*. And the [something] can be expressed by a  non-finite clause. Consider these analogues of the sentence you're trying to parse:

> The athlete has, as one of her goals, to run the mile in under four minutes.
>
> The volunteer fire department has, as its fund-raising goal, to reach $250,000 in donations by year-end.

The goal there is expressed as a *to* + infinitive clause.

These can be expressed in a different way,
as *[something] is someone's goal*, and again the [something] can be expressed by a non-finite clause:

> Running the mile in under four minutes is the athlete's goal.
>
> Reaching $250,000 in donations by year-end is the volunteer fire department's fund-raising goal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The sentence, as found in Scientific American, is correct; you merely have two coordinated clauses without repetition of the subject in the second.  "The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention **defines** STH and **has** STH TO DO." There is no criterion that allows one to assert that the conjoints are incongruous: in fact they are not since they inform the reader about the functions of the CDC.

Comment: I said it wasn't clear, not that it was incorrect. The criterion I employed was a stylistic one, not a grammatical one.  The first half of the sentence is about the CDC's definition of *social determinants of health*. That part of the sentence could have been eliminated. It is a damn clumsy sentence. IMO. A reader might wonder what these two parts of the sentence have in common. What they have in common is the theme of egalitarian health outcomes. But there's no good reason to start out defining jargon.

Comment: A simpler sentence would have been much better: **The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention has as one of its *Healthy People 2020* goals to "create social and physical environments that promote good health for all."**

Comment: The second sentence could have gone on to talk about the "social determinants" of health that present obstacles to that goal, and to explain what those determinants are in terms that would make sense to the lay person.

Answer (score 0):

PARSE:

The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention **defines** social determinants of health as “conditions in the places where people live, learn, work, and play” that affect their health outcomes
and
**has** as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals to “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.

*define* and *have* are the verbs used in this sentence for two predicates joined the linking word **and**.

Of course, *define* as a active verb is stronger than *have*, so it might be construed as a mistake at first glance. But it isn't.

Same pattern for have as x of y [direct object]
They have as one of their dogs, a coonhound.

Answer (score 0):

Your breakdown is correct, and both the *to*-infinitive phrase and the gerund phrase are possible. A noun phrase is possible too. Objects, all.

As you can see, though, your paraphrase in (d), while grammatical, practically forces an alternative reading of *has to* as a periphrastic modal meaning *must*:

> *The CDC [must] create social and physical environments that promote good health for all as one of its goals.*

So, for clarity, use quotes, keep the original order, or do both:

> *The CDC has “to create social and physical environments that promote good health for all” as one of its goals.*
>
> *The CDC has as one of its goals to create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.*
>
> *The CDC has as one of its goals “to create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.”* *

Or as you said, use a gerund phrase (or a noun phrase):

> *The CDC has creating social and physical environments that promote good health for all as one of its goals.*
>
> *The CDC has the creation of social and physical environments that promote good health for all as one of its goals.*

Here are some examples from Google Books, with and without quotes (except for noun phrases, which have no use for them):

> *Few people have as a goal **to become** a master tea
> brewer.* [Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Designing_for_Interaction/k28yVW3SEyYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22have+as+a+goal%22&pg=PA36&printsec=frontcover)
>
> *A less ambitious individual might have as a goal “**to survive** for
> the next 2
> years.”* [Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Psychology_of_Entrepreneurship/h_FfAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22have+as+a+goal+to%22&pg=PA105&printsec=frontcover)
>
> *Thus, as Phillips and Margolis themselves recognise, the neutralist
> liberal state will have as a goal **ensuring** that its citizens have
> the liberty to pursue their conceptions of the
> good.* [Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Capitalism_Corporations_and_the_Social_C/mLaYlt3eK64C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22have+as+a+goal%22&pg=PA118&printsec=frontcover)
>
> *Too often a group or organization will have as a goal
> “**implementing** a youth recreation program” rather than “**reducing**
> youth
> crime.”* [Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Research_Methods_for_Community_Change_A/lA5_J3l0dZYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22have+as+a+goal%22&pg=PA137&printsec=frontcover)
>
> *By performing one action, a human being can have as a goal **the
> performance** of a second
> action.* [Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ethics_of_Armed_Conflict/AiirBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22have+as+a+goal%22&pg=PA79&printsec=frontcover)

---

* <sub>While *Scientific American*’s mid-sentence quoting is technically correct based on the source at [CDC Healthy People 2020](https://www.cdc.gov/dhdsp/hp2020.htm), moving the open quote before the *to* would help a lot. Or to remain strictly correct: *The CDC has as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals “to . . . create social and physical environments that promote good health for all.”*</sub>

Comment: The parse by the OP is not accurate. This isn't either: The prepositional phrase "as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals"

Comment: @Lambie — It’s correct. What are you calling *as one of its Healthy People 2020 goals*?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with (a) and (b).  However, I feel the original sentence is a bit awkward. My suggestion would be to paraphrase as follows:

The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention defines social determinants of health as “conditions in the places where people live, learn, work, and play” that affect their health outcomes and **includes “create social and physical environments that promote good health for all” among its Healthy People 2020 goals.**

Comment: This is worse than the original. You probably want "to" before "create".